# Notify when pub/sub done

Tags: javascript, node.js, publish-subscribe

i have users class and gallery class. each gallery related to a user.
in gallery class, i want to do something like this:

```
users.on('remove', function(userId) {
   return gallery.removeByUser(userId); // promise!
});
```

in users i will write something like:

```
function removeUser(id) {
   var result = users.emit('remove', id);
   // I WANT result TO BE A PROMISE THAT RESOLVE WHEN ALL OF THE LISTENERS
   // DONE, IT IS POSSIBLE?
}
```

it's possible to wait for all of the listeners promises until they done?

i'm sure it's possible to build my own pub/sub.. i am looking for existing
library for that. (i need pub/sub that support it in the current session,
i don't need it to support in multiple instances)

thanks!

Comment: I think you can extract the deferred object from jquery.js, it's probably almost standalone: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/.

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q, https://github.com/maslennikov/node-flowy, https://github.com/caolan/async, amoung others.

Comment: i want to use pub/sub, not deferred only... how can i know when all of the listeners done with jquery deferred?

Comment: 1. pub/sub is the foundation of promises. 2. read the doc OO'

Comment: sorry for confusing... i know that pub/sub is the foundation of promises. however, promises are limited in this case. i just trying to find out if there are solution for something like: object.publish('someEvent').then(function() { LISTENERS_DONE! });

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple pub/sub I recommend using Redis.
Keep track of the clients in a topic and on remove let them be removed.
You can then write some logic around when for example there are no more subscribers on the topic.